# Running REST/WCF as STA instead of MTA for COM

Tags: wcf, com, rest, sta, mta

Is it possible to configure a [REST](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_State_Transfer) (WCF) service to run as [STA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Component_Object_Model#Threading) instead of [MTA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Component_Object_Model#Threading)?

This is approach is needed in order to run legacy COM objects. In order to configure ASMX web services to run as STA instead of MTA, there is a workaround available that uses an HTTPHandler to force the web service to run as STA.

An article by Jeff Prosise, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163544.aspx, details the workaround and how to apply it. Applying the same HTTPHandler to a REST-based WCF service (using *Create New ADO.NET Data Service* in Visual Studio) produces an error at the point at which the WebServiceHandlerFactory is called (it's being passed the HTTPContext, URL, etc.).

The handler works for ASMX web services, and I am able to add a WebMethod that returns the threading model as STA. However, even after setting ASPCompatibility (both in `web.config` and at the class level), the custom HTTPHandler always produces an error at the same point when trying to use a REST service. I've not configured any endpoints, since I am using a basic REST service with a couple of "service operator" methods.  The error is:

> Unable to cast object of type 'System.Web.Compilation.BuildResultCustomString'
>   to type 'System.Web.Compilation.BuildResultCompiledType'.

Comment: The MSDN link is effectively broken (it redirects to a generic MSDN Magazine page).

Answer (score 0):

Read [Integrating with COM+ Applications](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733094.aspx) and see if that gets you anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

I'm coming from the opposite direction (trying to convert my STA COM to MTA), and I believe it is automatic, if you instantiate the COM within your service instance and your COM is a proper STA with the proper registry entry. This is the way it worked for me, and I created at least 5 wrappers for this COM.

If you are creating threads manually, you may want to use *SetApartmentState*.